# Queue not working for structs defined inside functions

Tags: gcc, struct, queue

I'm using gcc.
I want to create a queue of my own datatype.

In the following code, when I declare `struct` outside main(), it works fine but it gives compile-time errors when that `struct` is defined inside.

```
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct tempPos {int a; int b;};   //....(1)
    queue<tempPos> b; //works only if tempPos is defined outside main
    queue<int> x;     //works fine anyways
    return 0;
}
```

Following are the errors.

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:10:15: error: template argument for ‘template<class _Tp> class std::allocator’ uses local type ‘main()::tempPos’
test.cpp:10:15: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class _Tp> class std::allocator’
test.cpp:10:15: error: template argument 2 is invalid
test.cpp:10:18: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
Compilation failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ forbids using locally-defined classes with templates because they have no linkage. The standard says:

> **14.3.1/2:** .A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.

Comment: But what if I want to have everything within the function itself? I don't want to create temporary structs outside. Is there any way?

Comment: Well, you cannot have the class definition inside the function. Why not put it just above the function in question? There is no overhead associated with it, and it's still reasonably close for reference (even though any decent editor/IDE could show it to you anyway).

Comment: You are right. But I was trying to avoid that. It seemed unstructured to me.